# Launcher activity shows up as blank screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm making a splash screen for my app and I'm just testing out putting the primary thread to sleep instead of using a timer. My code is:

```
package com.example.somu.activityswitcher;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void firstActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        TextView countDown = findViewById(R.id.count);
        for (int cd=3;cd>0;cd--) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                countDown.setText(Integer.toString(cd));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        firstActivity();
    }
}
```

While the MainActivity loads after 3 seconds, the splash screen (LauncherActivity) is a mere blank screen! What's going on here?!

**activity_launcher.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.somu.activityswitcher.LauncherActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:scaleX="0.25"
        android:scaleY="0.25"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/count"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Switching in..." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

How do I fix this?!

**NOTE:** I'm not bothered about *any way* to fix this.. I want to know why exactly this method won't work, and what is the next best way without explicitly using a timer.

Comment: Replace that lame busy loop with `postDelayed()` and proper `Runnable`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski of course that'd work. Read my original question in case you already didn't. I didn't wanna use any timer, and just wanted to know why this wouldn't work. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski oh, and the only reason I used that loop was to show the countdown on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, 
 may be this is useful to you.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView countDown;
int cd;

public void firstActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

    countDown = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);

    try {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (cd = 3; cd > 0; cd--) {
                  countDown.setText(Integer.toString(cd));
                }
                firstActivity();

            }
        }, 3000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

if you want to add countdown than put this insted of handler,

```
   new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            countDown.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            countDown.setText("done!");
            firstActivity();
        }

    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Thread.sleep(1000);` in the main thread which is freezing your UI.

**Since the UI thread is frozen, in the meantime, the activity will fail to inflate and render, resulting a mere blank screen.**

However, you can use `Thread.sleep` in a background thread but you can't update UI directly from a background Thread. You can use `runOnUiThread` to update UI from background thread if you place you countdown code inside a `Thread`

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //countdown code.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                textView.setText(...
            }
        });
    }
}).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep(1000);` freezing your `UI`.

try this

```
Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 3000, 1000); // delay*/
    }

private class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    i++;
                    Log.e("title", "" + i);
                    tv.setText(i + "");
                    if (i == 3) {
                        timer.cancel();
                        firstActivity();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code to handle the ticker on the screen to show a basic countdown? That's the entire reason I wrote the loop in the first place! At least read my code and understand my requirements before answering?!

Comment: @SomenathSinha got the solution check update ans its working fine in my device

Comment: Didnt. Vote gets locked in 15mins after voting, incase you didnt know. :)

Comment: @SomenathSinha did you try the above code i have tested it and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `Thread.sleep(1000);`

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                    countDown.setText(Integer.toString(l/1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                firstActivity();
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) to display timer instead of Thread or Handler as below :

`onTick()` run on UI thread so you can update UI in this method as you trying to show (3,2,1) on countDown `TextView`.

`onFinish` called when given timer is complete so you can write your code here after timer completed as you trying show another activity.

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         countDown.setText(""+ (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         firstActivity();
     }
  }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code.

 Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
           }
    }, 1000);
```